# Collider with a boolean

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider

I have been working on this problem for some days now and would appreciate it if anyone can help me out. So, I am trying to make a simple board game on unity and trying to trigger an event (ex. getting a card) when a player stops at a specific waypoint. I have a boolean for hasStopped in another class called (Moving) that becomes false when the dice are clicked and true when the player has stopped moving.

Now, my game used to work with this code:

```
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{ 
    if (hasStopped) 
    { 
        GetCardmethod(); 
    } 
}
```

but I'm not sure what I changed that this method stopped working. I checked in other methods to see that my boolean is getting updated properly, and I'm not sure what the problem is. I think my collider is detecting the boolean too early before it changes, but I don't know what to do to make this work. Like how would I get this game to only trigger the event if the player lands on the specific waypoint with the dice? Thank you

Comment: Are you sure `hasStopped` is already true the moment the player enters the collider and `OnTriggerEnter2D` is called? Maybe you rather want to go for [`OnTriggerStay2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay2D.html) which is called each `FixedUpdate` while the player is within the trigger. Then if he stops moving while inside you want to call your reaction **once** (e.g. additional bool flag or deactivate the collider until the next turn)

Comment: If `hasStopped` is in another class and is an instance variable, you need a reference to an object of this class `otherObject.hasStopped`. If it is a static variable, you must access it through the class name `Moving.hasStopped`. In both cases it must either be `internal` or `public`.

Comment: Please edit the question to include a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Check this solutions if they work for you:

1. If you have a 3d collider then you should use OnTriggerEnter() rather than OnTriggerEnter2D()
2. If your boolean hasStoped is in another cs script then you should make a reference to that script and access the boolean from there.
3. You might also want to check of the collision detection is continuous.